# Documentation editing does not warn when closing, or preserve edit state

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I was modifying a piece of documentation, and I mistakenly hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut on my keyboard.  As part of my natural instinct, I reopened the closed tab, only to find that none of my changes were preserved.  This caused me to immediately lose the documentation that I was editing, which forced me to start over again.

Luckily, I didn't lose much.  The change I had made was small at the time, but I was working on making a much, much larger one.  It would have easily caused me to abandon ship had this change been lost.

On the main site, I *usually* have the body of the question saved in some intermediate state, even if it's not complete, and I also get an alert asking if I *really* want to close the tab.  We definitely want that functionality in Documentation.

Comment: This is more [tag:feature-request] than [tag:bug] but still valid

Comment: @DanielM.: I'm describing it as a bug since not being warned that I was navigating away from a page with changes pending is a significant break from the norm, and very dangerous if one suffers from motion tics which would cause certain keys to be pressed instead of others.

Comment: Is this still true? I get a warning now.

Comment: I'll verify this when I get back to a computer.  Shouldn't take long.

Comment: @JonEricson:  Yeah, I see the same warning dialog too.  I'm guessing that this particular usability bug was fixed between then and now.  I don't see any way now that I'd be broken since the alert dialog would actively prevent my scenario from taking place.